# decimal values are working on the emulator but not on the actual phone

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

my app is running properly on the xamarin android emulator (API 22) but is crashing when i run the app on the actual phone (also API 22) and enter decimal values. (emulator handles the decimals properly)
here is how my edittext field in the axml file looks like.

```
             <EditText
        android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/inputA"
        android:layout_marginRight="250dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp" />
```

Then I access it using FindViewById method.

```
         a = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.inputA);
```

When user press button i'm converting the edittext input like so:

```
          double factorA = Convert.ToDouble(a.Text);
```

i have multiple edittext fields, im dealing with them with exactly same way as described above and after converting them to double i'm doing my calculations.

EDIT:
someone might find this helpful, instead of using

```
               double factorA = Convert.ToDouble(a.Text);
```

i used

```
      double factorA = double.Parse(a.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and it seems to to work ;)

Comment: If the app crashes, there's probably something in the log. That's what you should look at...

Comment: You can also perform debugging on the actual phone (rather than the emulator) as well which should help you to identify the problem quickly. Just enable USB debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can try parse with this way

```
Double factorA = Double.valueOf(a.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using comma or period to separate your decimal part of the number?

Read this documentation [Parsing Numeric Strings](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo/) to learn more about it.